# Python Randomized Characters

Tags: python, terminal

What I'm trying to do is create a jackpot game in the python terminal that basically requires randomization. so I created a function that defines what the jackpot does.

it'll automatically start when typed the specific word. here is the code that I created.

```py
jackpot_emojis = ["⚡", "⭐", "✨"]
jackpot_return = random.choice(jackpot_emojis)

print(jackpot_return + " | " + jackpot_return +  " | " + jackpot_return)
print(jackpot_return + " | " + jackpot_return +  " | " + jackpot_return)
print(jackpot_return + " | " + jackpot_return +  " | " + jackpot_return)
```

but it doesn't randomize the three emojis. if anyone can explain the output of this function, please do..

Comment: You call `random.choice` once, so one emoji is randomly selected. Then you print it nine times.

Comment: You only call `random.choice()` once, assign the return to `jackpot_return` and print that value out multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
jackpot_return = random.choice(jackpot_emojis)
```

Sets the variable `jackpot_return`. Each subsequent usage of that uses the same value. To get a new value, you must re-assign a new value to that variable.

To see this add this line to your program:

```
print(random.choice(jackpot_emojis) + " | " + random.choice(jackpot_emojis) +  " | " + random.choice(jackpot_emojis))
```

You probably want to something along these lines:

```
jackpot_emojis = ["⚡", "⭐", "✨"]
for _ in range(3):
    spinners = [random.choice(jackpot_emojis) for i in range(3)]
    print(" | ".join(spinners))
```

Comment: Thanks, Nathaniel. I should look carefully into my codes next time.

Comment: No problem; made a minor update showing some more idiomatic ways of building and printing these sorts of lists. Also be sure to choose and answer and upvote answers that are helpful - it makes the SO feedback loop work!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling random.choice in the beginning and then using the same variable value everywhere, you need to call it every time you need a random value. Also, you can avoid typing the same print statement multiple times and use a loop to run in N times:

```
jackpot_emojis = ["⚡", "⭐", "✨"]
n = 3

for i in range(n):
   print(random.choice(jackpot_emojis) + " | " + random.choice(jackpot_emojis) +  " | " + random.choice(jackpot_emojis))
```